# How to enable Analytics in Telerik Hybrid App

Tags: mobile, telerik, analytics, hybrid-mobile-app, telerik-appbuilder

I am trying to enable Analytics in a Hybrid App that i am developing. As per the instruction in the telerik docs, i enabled analytics in my application and after that i am able to see Data in the Live Tab. But i am not able to see any data on any other tab. I enabled the automatics reporting while enabling anaytics.

Is there anything else to be done. Should i add any code or something into my project for monitoring data. Basically i am looking for data that will give me sessions and installed platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you will have lots of information collected: sessions, users, location, hardware info, os info, etc.

Make sure to select the "Live Mode" radio button in the time period selector at the top of the dashboard. This is needed to see the data you are looking for, until the data has been fully processed.

I am the Product manager for Telerik Analytics. Feel free to reach out!

Comment: That did the trick. i didnt see that live button in the dashboard panel.

I have one more doubt, is it possible to get individual usage details from Telerik Dashboard. Suppose a person ABC uses the app for a particular time and XYZ uses for a particular amount of time, can i get these 2 insights from the Dashboard separately.

Comment: Yes, you should use the InstallationID property. You can set this during initialization of the monitor. Then you can filter any view with the same ID as part of a Data Study. It does require that you know the IDs to apply the filter. Also be cautious about privacy issues. In many contries you need to ask your client for consent if you monitor behavior that can be linked to individual persons.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking for a more specific data. Suppose a user is using my app with username abc@abc.com. I want to know for how much time the specific user has used the app. Can i do that with Telerik Analytics?

Comment: Yes. Set the InstallationID property, and use Feature Timings to measure whatever time you are interested in. Then you can run a Data Study on the Feature Timing view. But if you need to see the exact times in a list then this is not possible unless we create a custom script for you, that you can run on-demand.